# mysql query executed successfully but no changes in row

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i have created a php file for update info in mysql db. it'll get the input from a html form & then update data by matching ID. here is it:

```
<?
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("workshop", $con);
$sql = "UPDATE apply 
          SET staffname=' ".$_POST['name']." ', 
              staffno=' ".$_POST['contact']." ',
              staffemail=' ".$_POST['mail']." ',
              staffaddress=' ".$_POST['address']." ',
              paytype=' ".$_POST['paytype']."'
        WHERE 
            staffid=' ".$_POST['ic']." '";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
printf("Records updated: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
    if($result){
        echo "Successful";
}
    else {
        echo "ERROR";
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

its executing nicely but the problem is there is no effect on the table row. even i run the query on **phpmyadmin** but no luck! can anyone tell me where is the bug? thank you!

Comment: you should not use mysql_ API in news code, you **should prefere** PDO or mysqli with prepared statement for example.

Comment: your code is open for sql injection

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Are you sure you want to add spaces around your strings?

Comment: Shouldn't `$_POST['ic']` be "id"?!

Comment: @artragis, so i've to use mysqli/PDO instead of mysql_API everywhere?

Comment: @artragis, space may be a typo.

Comment: according to Ravi's answer it was not.

Comment: @artragis, so is it better to use mysqli in terms of security reason?

Comment: security, performance and also every functionatlities that mysql 5.X brough that mysql_ API does not handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `apply`
        SET `staffname` = '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']) . "',
            `staffno` = '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['contact']) . "',
            `staffemail` = '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['mail']) . "',
            `staffaddress` = '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['address']) . "',
            `paytype` = '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['paytype']) . "'
        WHERE `staffid` = '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['ic']) . "'";
```

**EDIT**

**It is always better to use PDO or mysqli instead of mysql_* functions**
but for now the above solution may work.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of things to say in your code:

first you use mysql_ API though it is deprecated, you should use PDO or mysqli.

Then, you add white spaces each time and it not good for matching ids.

And , you are vulnerable to sql injections.

I will give you the code with mysqli api as you just have to strip the "i" to get a code with mysql_ api

```
$sql = "UPDATE apply 
      SET staffname='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['name'])."', 
          staffno='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['contact'])."',
          staffemail='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['mail'])."',
          staffaddress='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['address'])."',
          paytype='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['paytype'])."'
    WHERE 
        staffid='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['ic'])."'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
printf("Records updated: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
if($result){
    echo "Successful";
}
else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
```

Comment: thanks for your code:) let me find how to connect via mysqli, then i must use this code! thanks a lot again!

Comment: i got an error like **Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\work\edit_data.php on line 35**

line 35: `SET staffname='".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])."',`

Comment: ok you have to give the mysqli connection ressource as a parametter like in query. It's for beeing sure of the encoding your database uses.

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit your query or set autoCommit flag to true (if such a thing exists in your context).

Does your where-Clause match any records? Does `printf("Records updated: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());` print some number of affected rows?

Maybe `staffid=' ".$_POST['ic']." '"` doesn't match any record due to the enclosing spaces, as artragis mentioned.

Comment: he uses mysql_query, and by default the autocommit flag is true.

Comment: OK, then let's hope that his environment uses the default.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: That's not much of a stretch; the change is breaking enough that you'd have to be a fool to set it as the global default.

Answer (score 0):

I would be careful using this code in production because it looks vulnerable to SQL injection. I would check out PDO for making safe mysql database communication.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/02/sql-injection-attacks/

If you haven't already done this, be sure to log or echo the $_POST['ic'] variable to ensure that it is set to what you believe it to be.

Answer (score 0):

The code is opened for SQL injections in a very bad way. Please do not use it on your website. Use PDO or MySQLi functions.

But your does have a spacing problem.

```
staffid=' ".$_POST['ic']." '";
```

should be

```
staffid='".$_POST['ic']."'";
```